# jQuery showing other users on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where each logged in user is shown as a `<div>` at a custom position, is it possible to show where the user's `<div>` is for other people.

I was hoping I could do this in (near) real time.

Just a nod in the right direction again would be fine.

Cheers

*edit: is there a way to do this without MySQL?*

Comment: What do you mean by 'show where the user's `<div>` is for other people'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally check out projects like http://www.ape-project.org/ which are ajax push engines.  Cometd type implementations may be more what you need if you want to go that direction.

Answer (score 1):

use ajax to check who is connected(thru mysql or anything) and then update your divs with that info. You could pull data every second-minutes whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can send position of user's `<div>` via php script and store it somewhere(database, file). And for every user get position of all divs from file/database and display them.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for?
http://api.jquery.com/offset/

you wont get arround saving the div position serverside and serving it to everybody
then get the result of that via setInterval to update the positions via a js function

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look a node.js, there's a good example of multi-user collaboration [here](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/experimenting-with-node-js/)